# Converting wmv to mp4 using ffmpeg

Tags: video, ffmpeg, codec, wmv

I want convert wmv file to mp4 using ffmpeg. Video details 1920x1080, total bitrate 7978kbps, frame rate 29 fps. Image slideshow, no audio. It show audio data, but there was no option to disable audio when I created wmv.

```
ffmpeg -i input.wmv -c:v libx264 -crf 23 output.mp4
```

Should I use command above or there is better settings to compress video without losing picture quality? (as it just static images, animation is only transitions effect between frames)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To disable audio you must use [-an](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Audio-Options).

> -an (output) Disable audio recording.

Since you are targeting a specific bitrate you should look into Two-Pass encoding. You can find the FFmpeg H.264 Encoding Guide discussing Constant Rate Factor (CRF) vs Two-Pass ABR [here](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.264).

Comment: Like this: `ffmpeg -i input.wmv -c:v libx264 -crf 23 -preset medium  -tune stillimage -an output.mp4` ?

Comment: Yes but `crf` doesn't guarantee a max bitrate. Take a look at the guide in the answer.

Comment: can you show an example for static images?

Comment: `stillimage ` should be OK